# Sonata Date range

Tags: symfony, date, sonata-admin, sonata

I have a small issue I am working on a small project using Sonata but I am trying to figure out how to customize the date range which a person can choose a date, example from 1 January 2000 to 31 December 2020. Could someone tell me where I can find it in the Sonata documentation or show me how to do it ? Because I have a little look and I have nothing to completely customize the choice of dates.

Thanks in advance

Edit :

In symfony documentation I found this

```
'days' => range(1,31)
```

Here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html

But I can't found anything in the sonata doc. And not working like on Symfony :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you use **sonata_type_date_picker** field in Sonata. Documentation is [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/form_types.html). Then your case can be implemented like this:

```
->add('userDate', 'sonata_type_date_picker', [
    'dp_min_date' => 'Jan 1, 2000', //todo: date format here depends on your setup. Basicly it's the same format, you see in text field after you selected data in datepicker.
    'dp_max_date' => 'Dec 31, 2020',
]);
```

Alternatively you can have date selector with 3 dropdowns - it's standard Symfony **date** field, works fine with SonataAdmin:

```
->add('userDate', 'date', [
    'years' => range(2000, 2020),
]);
```

I would also recommend to add backend validation with the same rules (in Entity):

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime()
 *
 * @Assert\Range(
 *      min = "2000-01-01",
 *      max = "2020-12-31"
 * )
 */
protected $userDate;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I used it but I can't pick them. Now it's like a text area before I was using ->add('userDate', 'date', ....)  and I was able to pick it. It was more easier for the users. Do you know how I can do that with 'sonata_type_date_picker'

Comment: So, do you want 3 drop downs or a date picker? In case of date picker you will see text input. You need to add some JavaScript to page (can be done via config) and then you will see datepicker in addition to text input.

Comment: If it's possible to have a 3 drop down it will be perfect